# there is some extra box in the output of a table

Tags: html

```html
<table color="" border="5" border color="" cell padding="3" cell spacing="0" width="560">
  <tr>
    <Th col span="4">TITLE
      <Th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <Th col span="2">Subtitle</Th>
    <Th col span="2">Subtitle</Th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <Th>1 item</Th>
    <Th>123</Th>
    <Th>1 item</Th>
    <Th>123</Th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <Th>1 item</Th>
    <Th>123</Th>
    <Th>1 item</Th>
    <Th>123</Th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <Th>1 item</Th>
    <Th>123</Th>
    <Th>1 item</Th>
    <Th>123</Th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <Th col span="2"> Sub Subtitle</Th>
    <Th col span="2">Sub Subtitle</Th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[in the first row there is an additional box while there are four columns and i used col span in TD tag in the first row of col span="4".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HflaR.png)

**There is an box in an output but without any extra column. i checked the code but didn't found anything. I tried to change the col span value but it didn't work and i even refreshed the page several times**

Comment: typo 'col span' = 'colspan', this should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it's working absolutely fine. I don't see any extra box or a column. Can you try ensuring that the attributes `col span`, `cell spacing`, and `cell padding` are written together **without any spaces** as `colspan`, `cellspacing`, and `cellpadding`. I just made the above changes in the code below.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Practice of table
    </title>
</head>
<body>
  <table color="" border="5" bordercolor="" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="560">
    <tr>
      <Th colspan="4">TITLE</Th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <Th colspan="2">Subtitle</Th>
      <Th colspan="2">Subtitle</Th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <Th>1 item</Th>
      <Th>123</Th>
      <Th>1 item</Th>
      <Th>123</Th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <Th>1 item</Th>
      <Th>123</Th>
      <Th>1 item</Th>
      <Th>123</Th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <Th>1 item</Th>
      <Th>123</Th>
      <Th>1 item</Th>
      <Th>123</Th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <Th colspan="2"> Sub Subtitle</Th>
      <Th colspan="2">Sub Subtitle</Th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wrote the code without any spaces between the colspan cellspacing and cellpadding but while i was posting it didn't let me post until i gave space in between them. and now i tried it again now it shows the correct output  .But it still thanks for confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the correct markup. You have missed to close first **th** and also it should be **colspan** rather than **"col span"**.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Practice of table
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <table color="" border="5" bordercolor="" cell padding="3" cellspacing="0" width="560">
        <tr>
            <Th colspan="4">TITLE</Th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <Th colspan="2">Subtitle</Th>
            <Th colspan="2">Subtitle</Th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <Th>1 item</Th>
            <Th>123</Th>
            <Th>1 item</Th>
            <Th>123</Th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <Th>1 item</Th>
            <Th>123</Th>
            <Th>1 item</Th>
            <Th>123</Th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <Th>1 item</Th>
            <Th>123</Th>
            <Th>1 item</Th>
            <Th>123</Th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <Th colspan="2"> Sub Subtitle</Th>
            <Th colspan="2">Sub Subtitle</Th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are quite right. I have done a small correction of adding `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags. Also, replaced all the `<th>` tags with `<td>` inside the `<tbody>` tag.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Practice of table
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table
      color=""
      border="5"
      bordercolor=""
      cell
      padding="3"
      cellspacing="0"
      width="560"
    >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">TITLE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Subtitle</th>
          <th colspan="2">Subtitle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tody>
        <tr>
          <td>1 item</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>1 item</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1 item</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>1 item</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1 item</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>1 item</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Sub Subtitle</td>
          <td colspan="2">Sub Subtitle</td>
        </tr>
      </tody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```